# Cordova wkwebviewonly for ios 6.1

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

Im using node.js with Cordova for iOS. I upgraded to Cordova 10.0.0 and it doesn't seem to include the wkwebviewonly support. It still seems to reference UIWebView. I wanted to use the wkwebviewonly plugin and everyone seems to have issues when using it with iOS 6 or higher. I have iOS 6.1. Can anyone give insight or help with this? Is there any solution aside fro downgrading to iOS 5? I am new to everything so I may be missing something here. Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: I went through it, https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html, says wkwebviewonly plugin  is obsolete and must be removed.  ios6+ does not contain UIwebview.  You can no longer submit an app with traces of UIwebview.

Comment: Thank you so much! so from what I gather in Cordova 10.0.0 you dont need to add the wkwebviewonly plugin you only need to remove the UIwebview references. Correct?

Comment: After ios 6+ platform no need for wkwebviewonly plugin.  It will pass apple app store inpection.